# How to control glassfish module startup order

Tags: module, glassfish, startup, concurrency

I have several web modules. There are dependency between them, say during startup, module B will use MBean exposed by module A. How to configure glassfish to enable it start them by specific order? Or is it possible to configure it to load them concurrently.

I searched quite a lot via google, but not result.

BTW, I'm using glassfish-2

Comment: you may want to describe the dependency more completely or include explicit error messages in your question.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://forums.java.net/node/884869) indicates that initial deployment order defines the startup order. I have found (on Glassfish 3) that the order is stored in domain.xml so you can swap entries in there.

Comment: Changing order in domain.xml did the trick for me in Glassfish 3.2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

If they're part of the same EAR and you're willing to move to Java EE 6 and thus GlassFish 3, here's a solution for you : http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/module_initialization_order_in_java

Answer (score 0):

GF 3.1 seems to reset the order after editing the domain.xml.